# How to integrate npm build process in maven java project

Tags: java, npm, build, maven-plugin, production-environment

I have some dependencies like jQuery, Bootstrap, Moment etc. which are currently being used in my project. What I want is rather than manually adding dependency files in the source code, they should get downloaded in the build process in a manner that I can use them in my project.

Comment: Its a multi-module project.

Comment: Have you a package.json wich all dependency that you need?

Comment: Yes! I created a package.json
{
"name" : "AccountLib",
"version":"0.0.1",
"dependencies":{
    "jquery":"3.6.0",
    "bootstrap":"4.6.0"
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you are using a project with multiple modules. A portion of modules affects the frontend using dependencies via npm. Another part I believe is in java and the dependencies are handled by maven. If you want more information on the backend, however, you have to tell me the framework you are using for java (Spring, Play ...). As for the frontend you have to populate the `node_modules` folder by downloading the dependencies that are indicated inside the `package.json`. The `npm install` command will populate the node_modules folder. If you need more info edit your post with more relevant informations.

Comment: I am using Spring framework. I was able to get the node_modules folder downloaded. But its out of scope for my html files in the webapp folder.
My frontend and backend files are in same project.